# Convert Timespan to string in LINQ

Tags: linq

Below is the LINQ Query:

```
 var data1 = (from p in DB.TProject
    from c in DB.TClient
    join ct in DB.TContract
    on c.ClientId equals ct.ClientId                                
     join cp in DB.TClientPortfolio
     on ct.ContractId equals cp.ContractId                                
    select new ClientReport
     {
    ClientName = c.ClientName,
    StartDate = ct.StartDate.ToString(),
     EndDate = ct.EndDate.ToString(),                                    
    DeliveryTime1 = Convert.ToString(cp.DeliveryTime1)
     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

here I need DeliveryTime in string where Delivery Time is in Timespan so want to convert it to string.
But is is showing error. Kindly help me
Thank you

Comment: Is it linq to entities with SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably LINQ provider don't know how to convert TimeSpan to string. So do that after returning data from the server.

```cs
var query = 
    from p in DB.TProject
    from c in DB.TClient
    join ct in DB.TContract on c.ClientId equals ct.ClientId                                
    join cp in DB.TClientPortfolio on ct.ContractId equals cp.ContractId                                
    select new
    {
        ClientName = c.ClientName,
        StartDate = ct.StartDate,
        EndDate = ct.EndDate,                                    
        DeliveryTime1 = cp.DeliveryTime1
    };

var data1 = query
   .Distinct()
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(c => new ClientReport
   {
        ClientName = c.ClientName,
        StartDate = c.StartDate.ToString(),
        EndDate = c.EndDate.ToString(),                                    
        DeliveryTime1 = Convert.ToString(c.DeliveryTime1)
   })
   .ToList();
```